# Implementation of snake game using sdl2 and c

Tags: c, game, sdl

I have implemented the snake game using sdl2 and c. The arrow keys are used for the movement of the snake and if the snake hits the boundary of the window, the game ends. I have not implemented score yet. How can I improve this? Also what should I use for better graphics, instead of using SDL_RenderDraw and SDL_RenderFill functions?

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

const SDL_Color BLACK = { .r = 0, .g = 0, .b = 0, .a = 255 };
const SDL_Color WHITE = { .r = 255, .g = 255, .b = 255, .a = 255 };

const SDL_Color RED = { .r = 255, .g = 0, .b = 0, .a = 255 };
const SDL_Color MAROON =  { .r = 128, .g = 0, .b = 0, .a = 255 };

const SDL_Color BLUE = { .r = 0, .g = 0, .b = 255, .a = 255 };
const SDL_Color NAVY = { .r = 0, .g = 0, .b = 128, .a = 255 };

const SDL_Color LIME = { .r = 0, .g = 255, .b = 0, .a = 255 };
const SDL_Color GREEN = { .r = 0, .g = 128, .b = 0, .a = 255 };

// 4:3 aspect ratio is assumed
//
// FIELD_CELL_WIDTH has to divisible by 4, will have to divide SCREEN_WIDTH
#define FIELD_CELL_WIDTH 16
#define CELL_SIZE ((SCREEN_WIDTH) / (FIELD_CELL_WIDTH))
#define FIELD_CELL_HEIGHT ((FIELD_CELL_WIDTH) / 4 * 3)

#define FIELD_START_CELL_X 0
#define FIELD_START_CELL_Y 0

void draw_field(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
    SDL_Color prev;
    SDL_GetRenderDrawColor(renderer, &prev.a, &prev.g, &prev.b, &prev.a);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, NAVY.r, NAVY.g, NAVY.b, NAVY.a);
    SDL_Rect field = {
        FIELD_START_CELL_X * CELL_SIZE,
        FIELD_START_CELL_Y * CELL_SIZE,
        FIELD_CELL_WIDTH * CELL_SIZE,
        FIELD_CELL_HEIGHT * CELL_SIZE
    };

    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &field);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, BLUE.r, BLUE.g, BLUE.b, BLUE.a);
    // SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 150, 255);
    for (int i = 1; i < FIELD_CELL_WIDTH; i++) {
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, i * CELL_SIZE, 0,
                i * CELL_SIZE, FIELD_CELL_HEIGHT * CELL_SIZE);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < FIELD_CELL_HEIGHT; i++) {
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 0, i * CELL_SIZE,
                FIELD_CELL_WIDTH * CELL_SIZE, i * CELL_SIZE);
    }

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, prev.a, prev.g, prev.b, prev.a);
}

bool is_cell_occupied[FIELD_CELL_HEIGHT][FIELD_CELL_WIDTH];

typedef struct apple {
    int r;
    int c;
} Apple;

Apple apple;

void place_apple()
{
    do {
        apple.r = rand() % FIELD_CELL_HEIGHT;
        apple.c = rand() % FIELD_CELL_WIDTH;
    } while (is_cell_occupied[apple.r][apple.c]);
}

void draw_apple(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
    SDL_Color prev;
    SDL_GetRenderDrawColor(renderer, &prev.r, &prev.g, &prev.b, &prev.a);
    // SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, RED.r, RED.g, RED.b, RED.a);

    SDL_Rect apple_cell = {
        .x = apple.c * CELL_SIZE, .y = apple.r * CELL_SIZE,
        .w = CELL_SIZE, .h = CELL_SIZE
    };
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &apple_cell);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, MAROON.r, MAROON.g, MAROON.b,
            MAROON.a);
    SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &apple_cell);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, prev.r, prev.g, prev.b, prev.a);
}

typedef enum dir {
    UP,
    DOWN,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT,
    NONE
} Dir;

// change in rows and cols when one moves in that direction by one cell
void get_dr_dc(int *dr, int *dc, Dir dir)
{
    switch (dir) {
    case UP:
        *dr = -1;
        *dc = 0;
        break;
    case DOWN:
        *dr = 1;
        *dc = 0;
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        *dr = 0;
        *dc = 1;
        break;
    case LEFT:
        *dr = 0;
        *dc = -1;
        break;
    default:
        *dr = 0;
        *dc = 0;
        break;
    }
}

typedef struct snake_segment {
    int r;
    int c;
    Dir dir;

    // struct snake_segment *next;
    // struct snake_segment *prev;
} SnakeSegment;

#define SNAKE_MAX_SIZE 10000

typedef struct snake {
    SnakeSegment segments[SNAKE_MAX_SIZE];
    int size;
} Snake;

Snake snake;

Dir snake_get_dir()
{
    if (snake.size == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return snake.segments[0].dir;
}

void snake_set_dir(Dir dir)
{
    if (snake.size != 0) {
        snake.segments[0].dir = dir;
    }
}

void snake_init_segment(int i)
{
    snake.segments[i] = (SnakeSegment){ 0, 0, RIGHT };
}

void snake_init(int size, int r, int c, Dir dir)
{
    snake.size = size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            snake.segments[i].r = r;
            snake.segments[i].c = c;
        } else {
            int dr, dc;
            get_dr_dc(&dr, &dc, snake.segments[i - 1].dir);
            snake.segments[i].r = snake.segments[i - 1].r - dr;
            snake.segments[i].c = snake.segments[i - 1].c - dc;
        }
        snake.segments[i].dir = dir;
        is_cell_occupied[snake.segments[i].r][snake.segments[i].c] = true;
    }
}

void snake_increment_size(const SnakeSegment *new_segment)
{
    snake.segments[snake.size++] = *new_segment;
}

bool is_valid_move(int new_head_r, int new_head_c)
{
    if (new_head_r >= FIELD_CELL_HEIGHT || new_head_r < 0 ||
            new_head_c >=FIELD_CELL_WIDTH || new_head_c < 0 ||
            (is_cell_occupied[new_head_r][new_head_c] &&
             !(new_head_r == snake.segments[snake.size - 1].r &&
                 new_head_c == snake.segments[snake.size - 1].c))) {
        // printf("False move: new_head_r = %d new_head_c = %d\n", new_head_r,
        //      new_head_c);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// will return false on invalid move
bool move_snake(bool *has_eaten_apple)
{
    *has_eaten_apple = false;
    int dr, dc;
    get_dr_dc(&dr, &dc, snake.segments[0].dir);

    if (!is_valid_move(snake.segments[0].r + dr, snake.segments[0].c + dc)) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = snake.size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i == snake.size - 1) {
            is_cell_occupied[snake.segments[i].r][snake.segments[i].c] = false;

            // get the change in head directions
            get_dr_dc(&dr, &dc, snake.segments[0].dir);
            // if eaten apple, increment the size
            if (snake.segments[0].r + dr == apple.r &&
                    snake.segments[0].c + dc == apple.c) {
                snake_increment_size(&snake.segments[snake.size - 1]);
                is_cell_occupied[snake.segments[i + 1].r][snake.
                    segments[i + 1].c] = true;
                *has_eaten_apple = true;
            }
        }

        get_dr_dc(&dr, &dc, snake.segments[i].dir);
        snake.segments[i].r += dr;
        snake.segments[i].c += dc;

        // for the head
        if (i == 0) {
            is_cell_occupied[snake.segments[i].r][snake.segments[i].c] = true;
        }
    }

    for (int i = snake.size - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
        snake.segments[i].dir = snake.segments[i - 1].dir;
    }

    return true;
}

void draw_snake(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
    SDL_Color prev;
    SDL_GetRenderDrawColor(renderer, &prev.a, &prev.g, &prev.b, &prev.a);
    for (int i = 0; i < snake.size; i++) {
        SDL_Rect cell = { snake.segments[i].c * CELL_SIZE,
            snake.segments[i].r * CELL_SIZE,
            CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE
        };

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, LIME.r, LIME.g, LIME.b, LIME.a);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &cell);

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,GREEN.r,GREEN.g,GREEN.b, 255);
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &cell);
    }

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, prev.a, prev.g, prev.b, prev.a);
}

void draw_screen(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    draw_field(renderer);
    draw_apple(renderer);
    draw_snake(renderer);
}

#define FRAME_RATE 60
// snake will move after N_FRAMES_PER_MOVEMENT frames
#define N_FRAMES_PER_MOVEMENT 10

void update_game_state()
{
    bool has_eaten_apple = false;
    if (!move_snake(&has_eaten_apple)) {
        exit(0);
    }

    if (has_eaten_apple) {
        place_apple();
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nUnable to initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    atexit(SDL_Quit);

    SDL_Window *window =
        SDL_CreateWindow("Snake",
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
        );
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1,
            SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

    // make the scaled rendering look smoother.
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "linear");
    SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize(renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    int quit = 0;
    snake_init(5, 0, 4, RIGHT);
    place_apple();
    draw_screen(renderer);
    bool last_move_drawn = true;
    int n_frames_mod = 0;
    while (!quit) {
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = 1;
                break;
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    quit = 1;
                    break;
                case SDLK_UP:
                    if (snake_get_dir() != DOWN && snake_get_dir() != UP &&
                            last_move_drawn) {
                        snake_set_dir(UP);
                        last_move_drawn = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    if (snake_get_dir() != UP && snake_get_dir() != DOWN &&
                            last_move_drawn) {
                        snake_set_dir(DOWN);
                        last_move_drawn = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    if (snake_get_dir() != RIGHT && snake_get_dir() != LEFT &&
                            last_move_drawn) {
                        snake_set_dir(LEFT);
                        last_move_drawn = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    if (snake_get_dir() != LEFT && snake_get_dir() != RIGHT &&
                            last_move_drawn) {
                        snake_set_dir(RIGHT);
                        last_move_drawn = false;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }

        if (n_frames_mod == 0) {
            update_game_state();
            last_move_drawn = true;
        }

        draw_screen(renderer);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        n_frames_mod = (n_frames_mod + 1) % N_FRAMES_PER_MOVEMENT;
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks very nice.

You have created `Apple`, `SnakeSegment` and `Snake` structs for storing data. 
It is good. 
And it is much better approach than separate variables (`int apple_r; int apple_c; ...`).

### Pass data to functions via parameters

Instead of using global variables directly form every functions:

```
void draw_apple(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
void draw_snake(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
```

I would use the following:

```
static void draw_apple(const Apple *apple_ptr, SDL_Renderer *renderer)
static void draw_snake(const Snake *snake_ptr, SDL_Renderer *renderer)
```

It would bring some benefits. For example: Possible to draw several Apples/Snakes with the same function.

### Use keyword static

If a function is used only in a C file where it is defined, 
then you should set it as a static function. It reduces visibility of the function to the compilation unit. That is more important when software gets bigger.

Same rule for global variables. 
Use:

```
static Snake snake;
```

instead of

```
Snake snake;
```

### And something about SDL2 interface

I don't like all parts of SDL2 interface, because it forces you to use this kind of code:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, LIME.r, LIME.g, LIME.b, LIME.a);
SDL_GetRenderDrawColor(renderer, &prev.r, &prev.g, &prev.b, &prev.a);
```

It would be more nice and powerful in this way:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, &LIME);
SDL_GetRenderDrawColor(renderer, &prev);
```

But that is not your fault.